# Dependent drop down in jquery mobile not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I am creating a dependent drop down list of states & city in jquery mobile. which is not working for me. I am unable to hide the 2nd drop down too. The code i am using is:

The html:

```
     <select name="selectmenu5" id="selectmenu5">
     <option value="0">Select State</option>   
     <option value="1">Andaman and Nicobar</option>  
     <option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>  
</select>

        <select name="selectmenu4" id="selectmenu4">
          <option class="city" id="1">Select City</option>
          <option class="city" id="2">option 2</option>
          <option class="city" id="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
```

and the js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selectmenu4").hide();
    $("#selectmenu5").live("change",function() {
       $("#selectmenu4").show();
        switch($("#this").val()){ 
            case "1":
                $(".city").hide().parent().find("#1").show();
                break;
            case "2":
                $(".city").hide().parent().find("#2").show();
                break;

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ids are: "selectmenu5" and "selectmenu4". The hide selector says "selectmenu6". what's going on there?

Comment: i had a ctrl + z their... my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WXbbj/40/

Create all the selects:

```
<select name="selectmenu5" id="selectmenu5">
 <option value="0">Select State</option>   
 <option value="1">Andaman and Nicobar</option>  
 <option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
```

```
    <select class='cityList' name="selectmenu1" id="selectmenu1">
      <option class="city" id="0">Select City</option>
      <option class="city" id="1">city1</option>
      <option class="city" id="2">city2</option>
</select>

 <select class='cityList' id="selectmenu2">
      <option class="city" id="0">Select City</option>
      <option class="city" id="1">city3</option>
      <option class="city" id="2">city4</option>
</select>
```

Basically i use css to hide the "selectmenu" :

```
#selectmenu1,#selectmenu2{
display:none;
}
```

And this is the jquery function to show only the right options:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {         
  $("#selectmenu5").on("change",function() {        
  $(".cityList").hide();         


  $("#selectmenu"+$(this).val()).show();
 }); });
```

Comment: I don't understand why but its not working for me. the drop down didn't change.

Comment: besides showing the results you want, you want it selected? explain further what you're needing.

Comment: I exactly needed what you showed. I want to display city drop down with respect to state drop down list.

Comment: still its not working have tried literally every thing but it's still not working. can it be my dreamweavers issue. coz I dont think so it'll work like this even if their is some problem.

Comment: I would have loved to have a single drop down menu and display the text with respect to the state's value. But I think if this thing works for me i'll settle on it. thanks alot for the help.